# Blue screen error 0xc000034

Tags: hard-drive

I downloaded Windows 8 and now PC (Dell Inspiron N5050) does not start and a blue screen with error 0xc000034 appears.
Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: You're going to have to give us more information than that for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

0xC0000034 is not officially referenced to as far as I can see, but it appears through research that this is due to a corrupt BCD store; so you'll need to reinstall Windows 8, if this keeps happening then contact Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks Tom.I cannot download W8 again since I cannot get past the blue screen.Microsoft could not help.I may have to buy the disc.Waiting to see if Dell can help